# jQuery - off method

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bind

I've bounded a click handler over an element which id is 'myId'. The code I've provided for doing so is:

```
$(document).on('click','#myId',function() {
    alert('Hello world!');
});
```

Then, when I wanted to unbind that handler I have tryied:

```
$('#myId').unbind('click');
$('#myId').off('click');
```

But it was no use. Does anybody have an idea concerning to this?, I mean, how could I do to unbind the click handler over 'myId' element? I must add that the click handler was added over an element that was created after loading the page.

Thanks,

PS: I have titled this as a GWT question, my apologize that was my fault.

**Edit: **

I have the following scenario: I create an element marked with 'myId', then attach a click handler to it and then I must remove that element. After a while I create that element again, and attach a new click handler. The problem is that the previous handler is not unbounded. I hope this would help.

Comment: Your selector is incorrect on your `.on` call. If it is an ID, it should be `#myId`

Comment: Is there any reason for adding your event to `$(document)` instead of `$('#myId')` directly? If you are not adding your element dinamically in the page, you can apply your click binding just by using `$('#myId').on('click', function() { /* ... */ });` or the shortcut `$('#myId').click(function() { /* ... */ });`.This way you can also disable it using `$('#myId').off('click');` as you are trying to.

Comment: Graham, you are absolutely right. I correct that immediately.

Comment: The problem is myId element is created after the page has been loaded. I've tryied that piece of code, but it was no use, when I clicked over the element nothing happened.

Comment: Just how I suspected. Then it's ok. :)

Comment: @TheBallman What you're using is called a delegated event handler, and is intended specifically for elements that are created after the page has loaded. There should be no need to bind event handlers again when you create those elements; that's what event delegation is there to avoid. The only time you *would* remove the existing one and bind a new one is if you wanted the functionality to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should invoke 'off' method on the document object, instead of the element you have bounded the click handler on. I.e.

```
$(document).off('click','#myId');
```

I've faced that before, and that piece of code worked for me.

Comment: "You should invoke 'off' method on the document object, instead of the element you have bounded the click handler on" It **is** bound to the document, which is precisely *why* you have to call `.off()` on the document as well.